# Migration from SVN/FishEye to Git - Sync Not Working

Tags: git, svn, migration, jira, bitbucket

So I don't expect anyone to read the entire migration guides, but I am stuck at a point and right now Jira has been less than responsive to my issue. Here is the guides http://go-dvcs.atlassian.com/display/aod/Migrating+from+Subversion+to+Git+on+Bitbucket

I am migrating our Jira/SVN to BitBucket/Git and Jira has provided a migration guide. I am stuck at the "Sync" portion. Basically if you don't want to read the guides the process is:

1. Download the SVN dump file
2. Build a git clone of it
3. Sync new SVN commits to the clone until you are ready to upload. (Fetch/Rebase)
4. Upload the project to Git (Bitbucket)

I downloaded the dump and have my clones, but the guides say to run a `git svn fetch`. When I do this on projects that I KNOW for sure have commits after I made the dump file, nothing really happens as far as I can tell. There is no output during the `fetch` or the `rebase` and no new files are added to my physical local git repo, so it looks like the fetch isn't getting anything.

I know some of this is based on Jira's migration.jar file, so maybe some magic happens under the hood, but the fetch simply isn't getting anything.

My ignorant thought is that it's fetching from `svn://localhost/repos` which is where the initial clone came from. That is the folder where the dump was essentially extracted too. The migration guides don't say so, but I feel like I need to somehow tell it to fetch from my remote repo on Jira's servers. I was thinking somehow in the .jar file it's indicating to do that, but as far as I can tell, it fetches nothing.

Also note, I have to have `svnserve` running to run the fetch. If I do the fetch without `svnserve` running I get an error. This leads me to believe it's looking locally at my out of date dump and note remotely at the actual new commits on the cloud server.

Any thoughts on where to start? Has anyone else completed this process with any luck. I'm on Windows. Also, my repos that I know are old and have no new commits were uploaded successfully to Bitbucket so I think for the most part I am doing everything right.

Answer (score 0):

So just on a hunch I edited the config files in the .git folder and changed svn://localhost/ to my remote URL and everything seems to have worked. Strange I don't see this in the migration guides.